# Incorporate dropdownchecklist into JQuery-UI form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to incorporate a dropdownchecklist into a form and can't get the [DDCL](https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/) to show properly.  Here's a fiddle showing just the DDCL [working as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/delliottg/drQW3/).  I've incorporated it into a modified example from the [JQuery-UI modal form](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) with minor changes to the selector, here's that fiddle:  [Non-working example I'm trying to fix.](http://jsfiddle.net/delliottg/Mq7aC/)  It doesn't render a usable DDCL, just a tiny little box instead.  Click on the "Add New Instrument" button to see what I'm talking about.

Here's an HTML snippet from code I've got for reference here on SO (see "non-working example..." above for full code):

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<label for="modelNumber">Model Number</label>
<input type="text" name="modelNumber" id="modelNumber" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="partNumber">Part Number</label>
<input type="text" name="partNumber" id="partNumber" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="serialNumber">Serial Number</label>
<input type="text" name="serialNumber" id="serialNumber" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="services">Requested Services</label>
<select id="services" name="services" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Calibration">
        <option>Temperature</option>
        <option>Conductivity</option>
        <option>Pressure</option>
        <option>Dissolved Oxygen</option>
        <option>pH</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Repairs">
        <option>O-Ring Replacement &amp; Inspection</option>
        <option>Hydrostatic Test</option>
        <option>Diagnose &amp; Repair Problems</option>
        <option>Replace Anti-Foulant Devices</option>
        <option>Download Data From Instrument</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Third Party Sensors">
        <option>Fluorometer</option>
        <option>Transmissometer</option>
        <option>Turbidity</option>
        <option>SUNA</option>
        <option>PAR</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Here's the JS that makes it work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#services").dropdownchecklist();
});
```

What am I missing?  I can see that something get rendered beneath the label, but it's just a thin little box instead of the drop down box I'm expecting.  I suspect this could possibly be conflicting CSS?  I've removed the on-page CSS and get mostly the same results (unusable little box in all cases), and I'm pretty sure the External Resources are identical on both fiddles although maybe not in the same order.  I've added & removed most of them and tested, so I'm pretty sure the external resources are not the problem, although don't discount that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with what the dialog-form bit does with your select element.
You have to FIRST make the select into a ddcl, THEN call the dialog-form bit.

Just but the whole $( "#dialog-form").dialog({...}) bit after the $("#services").dropdownchecklist(); in your $(document).ready...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#services").dropdownchecklist();
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 350,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Instrument": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

          bValid = bValid && checkLength( modelNumber, "modelNumber", 1, 7 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( partNumber, "partNumber", 0, 8 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( serialNumber, "serialNumber", 1, 8 );

          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( modelNumber, /^[0-9]+[-]*[a-z]*[0-9]*[a-z]*$/i, "Model numbers consist of 0-9, a-z, hyphens, and begin with a number." );
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( partNumber, /^[0-9]*[-]*[a-z]*[0-9]*[a-z]*$/i, "Part numbers consist of 0-9, a-z, hyphens, and begin with a number, however there may not be one on your instrument, so leave this blank." );
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( serialNumber, /^[0-9]*[-]*[a-z]*[0-9]*[a-z]*$/i, "Serial numbers can concist of 0-9, a-z, hyphens, and begin with a number or letter." );

          if ( bValid ) {
            $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
              "<td>" + modelNumber.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + partNumber.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + serialNumber.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + services.val() + "</td>" +
            "</tr>" );
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });
    $( "#create-user" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
});
```

here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mq7aC/6/

Comment: Nice!  I knew I was missing something simple-ish, but it's late in the day on a Friday.  Thanks a lot for the super quick solution.